# About PhD in non-commutative topology

Tags: noncommutative-geometry

I am a 3rd year undergraduate student. What are the things that would be good to know if I apply for PhD? I want to do a PhD in non-commuative topology.

I am fascinated by this non-commutative aspect. I have no knowledge of $K$-theory or $C^{\ast}$-algebras yet. I  have read Hatcher upto homology. I am reading differential geometry fromm S. S. Chern and in analysis I am studying from Rudin's *Real and Complex Analysis* as well as *Functional Analysis*.

How much should I read in order to understand and from which books in order to understand non-commutative geometry fully?

Comment: You may want to try reading something like Kalkhali's  Very Basic Noncommutative Geometry http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0408416. Though in my (very limited) experience it's more effective to approach research by trying to tackle a specific problem and learning the tools you need as you go along.  In lieu of that, read as much operator algebra and geometry as you can.

Comment: Depending on what flavor non-commutative topology you want to learn a lot of homological algebra. You might want to start glancing at Weibel's An Introduction to Homological Algebra. It is my understanding that a lot of motivation comes from derived categories of varieties.

Answer (score 3):

Standard references for basic C*-algebra theory include:

[C*-Algebras by Example](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821805991) by Kenneth R. Davidson

[C*-Algebras and Operator Theory](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0125113609) by Gerard J. Murphy

[An Introduction to K-Theory for C*-Algebras](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521789443) by M. Rørdam, F. Larsen, N. Laustsen

In general, it seems safe to state that a solid knowledge of algebraic topology and functional analysis is useful for doing "non-commuative topology." If you have a background in algebraic topology, you might want to consider learning about K-theory in the commutative setting first, for example from Efton Park's [Complex Topological K-Theory.](http://ebooks.cambridge.org/ebook.jsf?bid=CBO9780511611476)